# Excel Interacting With Python

Tags: python, excel

**What tools have you seen for passing data into and out of MS-Excel?**

These is a request for advice about choice of tools, and for good technical articles available online. It's not a question about named methods and objects in wxpython.

**Background:**

I have the job or retiring or euthanatising a bunch of user-developed Microsoft Excel applications, and the end state is that the data storage and retrieval, and the data processing, will all reside and run on our company's servers, running on an existing company-wide platform of Python apps.

Some of these Excel workbooks will live on, calling data from our servers via Python apps - which will look a lot like the screens and menus of the existing Excel add-ins - and Excel will still be used for whatever local data-noodling our users choose to do. But the heavy lifting is moving to python on our servers, where we have a substantial codebase of python objects and tools.

We have a free hand in designing the tools and interfaces to do all this.

So the questions are:

1. What have you seen?
2. What tools are out there?
3. What pitfalls and pratfalls have you discovered?

The more we take out of Excel and VBA and run on servers, the happier I'll be. A lot of the VBA code and cell-based formula logic I'm looking at should have been retired years ago, and running it in a fragile desktop tool has obvious operational risks.

Note that we're going a bit further than 'Here, let me open a new Excel Worksheet, paste and format some data, and save the file' - we need to *interact* with existing Excel worksheets, open and running in existing sessions of Excel.exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds to me like what you are after is working directly with the Excel Component Object Model, using the pywin32 library. Going that route, you will have access to all of the excel functions through python. Take a look at Excel's COM interface reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861528.aspx

You will first need to install the [pywin32 library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/). Then get yourself acquainted with COM interactions from python. Here is a chapter from [*Python Programming on Win32*](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html) that should help you get started.

A basic introduction to using pywin32 to control Excel:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

>>> excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application') # get a handle to the Excel COM object
>>> workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('absolute\\path\\to\\workbook.xlsm') # open an existing excel workbook
>>> worksheet = workbook.Worksheets('Sheet1') # get the worksheet called "Sheet1"
>>> r = worksheet.Range('A1:A5')
>>> print r.Value
((u'Value of A1',), (u'Value of A2',), (u'Value of A3',), (u'Value of A4',), (u'Value of A5',))
>>>
>>> r.Value = range(5)
>>> print r.Value
((0.0,), (1.0,), (2.0,), (3.0,), (4.0,))
>>>
>>> workbook.Close()
>>> excel.Quit()
```

You can control any aspect of excel using the COM object. And if you first run `excel.Visible = 1`, you can watch all of your changes happen in real-time.

You need to be careful to properly close the excel object when using this api, however. If your program crashes or quits before properly calling `excel.Quit()` (and in some cases I've found that I must explicitly call `del excel`), then you will end up leaving an EXCEL.exe process running in the background.

Comment: You could also use the ActiveState version of Python which already includes pywin32 in it. http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads ...other than that I completely agree with Brian's approach.

Answer (score 2):

Well what I've done (munging and cleansing data from collections of Excel spreadsheets into an SQL backend) is quite a bit simpler than the functionality you're after, but xlrd is a real gem. It will let you surf Excel spreadsheets and work with their data quite naturally from within Python. I've worked with plenty of crappy and painful APIs, and xlrd is not one of them. I have not worked with its Excel-writing companion, xlwt, but based on my experience with xlrd, I have high hopes.

http://www.python-excel.org

Comment: Thanks - I was aware of xlrd, but the code I've seen could've been better. I may well have to become some kind of 'evangelist' for better use of xlrd and xlrt at my current employer: this is a somewhat daunting prospect for a beginner-to-intermediate Python coder.